# How to get SUM of only highest score in mysql and sort by category?

Tags: php, mysql

What I want to do is get the SUM of only highest score in my database and sort by category

**here is my database table**

```
question_id  score1 score2 score3 category_id 
-----------  ------ ------ ------ -----------
   1           4      3       1        1
   2           5      2       9        2
   3           7      2       1        1
   4           1      5       6        2
```

**What I want in my result**

```
it is only get the highest score to add
category_id 1 = score 11 (7+4)
category_id 2 = score 15 (9+6)
```

Any idea how to solve it using php or mysql?

thanks

Comment: Oscar, it just happens that in your test code, the gratest score corresponds to the category (category 1 has always the greatest score in score1, and category 2 in score3). I would be better if you could change that and update the expected result, because I see two different ways of answering your question based on that.

Comment: I'm a little disappointed that no one suggested normalisation as the answer to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need the [`GREATEST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function for that; it returns the biggest of all sums for the respective group.

```
SELECT category_id, GREATEST(SUM(score1), SUM(score2), SUM(score3))
FROM mytable
GROUP BY category_id;
```

Btw, this is different than calculating the sum of each greatest value per row. For that, you need to reverse `GREATEST` and `SUM`.

Comment: `GREATEST(SUM(score1), SUM(score2), SUM(score3))` OR `SUM(GREATEST(score1,score2,score3))`

Comment: @Jack : oh I see. So which one is more optimized withe lesser execution time?

Comment: @diEcho I'm not sure to be honest ... a max over the sums or a sum over the maxes ;-) sounds the same to me.

Comment: I am thinking to give you the correct mark or @joachim lasksson, because both of you the code also working, what can I do is I check the mysql speed performance before give the correct mark :)

Comment: @Oscar Sure, go for it :) I'd be interested to know.

Comment: Grats, your excute speed performance is faster than @joachim lasksson :)

Comment: @Oscar Do make sure it's also correct, as Alex and Joachim have pointed out.

Comment: @Oscar The points don't really matter, but note that the queries don't quite do the same thing :)

Comment: afterall reputation matters.. 50k >  40k :p

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GREATEST` to find the max of the columns, then `SUM` over that;

You're not quite making it clear if you want the sum of the highest scores per question, or the highest score overall, so I'll add both :)

This will give you the sum of the highest scores per question, that is, if score1 is highest on question1 and score2 is highest on question2, they'd be summed;

```
SELECT category_id,SUM(GREATEST(score1,score2,score3))
FROM questions
GROUP BY category_id
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2c15/1).

This will instead give you the highest total score of score1, score2 and score3, that is if score1's total is higher than score2's total, it will return the sum of score1;

```
SELECT category_id, GREATEST(SUM(score1),SUM(score2),SUM(score3))
FROM questions
GROUP BY category_id
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2c15/4).

Comment: I am thinking to give you the correct mark or @jack, because both of you the code also working, what can I do is I check the mysql speed performance before give the correct mark :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the right query to do that would be:

```
SELECT category_id, greatest(sum(score_1), sum(score_2), sum(score_3))
  from scores
  group by category_id;
```

That would give you the greatest of the scores per column.

But, you can do

```
SELECT category_id, sum(greatest(score_1,score_2,score_3))
  from scores
  group by category_id;
```

If you want the greatest for each row, and then sum them.

You can check the fiddle in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d7a2/5

Answer (score 0):

This may helps,

```
SELECT SUM(score1+score2+score3) AS score, 
             category_id FROM table GROUP BY question_id ORDER BY score desc
```